# Is it possible to call an API based on user roles with useSWR?

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I'm wondering if it is possible to use [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app) from Vercel if a condition is `true`? I.e., if RoleOne is true, then call:

```
let { data: roleOneData, error: roleOneError } = useSWR(
    "/api/getRoleOneInfo",
    fetcher
  )
```

My Next.js app is dealing with different user roles, and all user roles are sharing the same Application Shell, which means I call all user role specific API's in the Application Shell. I would like to only call the API I need if it can see a specific user role is true. I'm getting the roles from the `userData` API.

Here are my fetchers which are used in various functions:

```js
let { data: userData, error: userError } = useSWR("/api/getUserInfo", fetcher)

let { data: roleOneData, error: roleOneError } = useSWR(
    "/api/getRoleOneInfo",
    fetcher
  )

let { data: roleTwoData, error: roleTwoError } = useSWR(
    "/api/getRoleTwoInfo",
    fetcher
  )
```

If I'm logging in as `RoleOne`, I'm getting API errors for `getRoleTwoInfo` and vice versa. I would like to avoid calling RoleTwo API if I'm logged in as RoleOne and the other way around. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely possible and described in [this page](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching) in the documentation.

You just have to make your key (the url of the request in your case) to be falsy when you don't want the request to happen.

```js
let { data: userData, error: userError } = useSWR("/api/getUserInfo", fetcher)

let { data: roleOneData, error: roleOneError } = useSWR(
    userData?.role === "one" ? "/api/getRoleOneInfo" : null,
    fetcher
  )

let { data: roleTwoData, error: roleTwoError } = useSWR(
    userData?.role === "two" ? "/api/getRoleTwoInfo" : null,
    fetcher
  )
```